# WebDriverError: Cannot find elements when the xpath expression is null in javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I'm testing a login page on the remote server and selenium throws me the above error. But when I test the same code on a local server, it works perfectly. I'm unable to understand as to why the remote server would throw an error and the local server won't when the selenium version on both sites is exactly the same.
Initially, I used:

```
browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath(desiredXpath)).click()
```

to click on any button. Then I tried to make a method which only performs the click operation so that every click operation could be performed by this method itself. For that I used:

```
 browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', driver.findElement(By.xpath(desiredXpath)))
```

The above line executes perfectly on a local server but fails to recognise the xpath on the remote server and hence throws an error, WebDriverError: Cannot find elements when the xpath expression is null.

I used a console statement to print the xpath just before this line executes. It prints the xpath through which the element is to be located.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Also is the remote Server different OS compared to your local .. suspecting that you are may be not reading the xpath prop correctly on remote Server

Comment: I'm not sending any information to the remote server. I've cloned a branch on my local system as well as the remote server. I'm just accessing the server and running the tests there itself.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to [wait](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) for the element to become present:

```
var elm = element(by.xpath(desiredXpath));
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 5000);
elm.click();

// or browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elm.getWebElement());
```

Comment: @wolfsbane what was the error you were getting when you tried with the wait?

Comment: cannot read property of 'bind' of undefined at ExpectedConditions.presenceOf

Comment: I suspect that the error is due to `desiredXpath` being passed `null` on the remoteServer.. Can you update question with the logic on how this variable is being populated

Comment: I used the above wait mechanism as well as the following one:
browser.driver.wait(return browser.driver.isElementPresent(By.xpath(desiredXpath)))

Comment: I've already said that I used a console statement to print the 'desiredXpath' right before the click statement and it prints the correct xpath.

Comment: @wolfsbane that "cannot read property of 'bind' of undefined at ExpectedConditions.presenceOf" error - are you sure you've tried the posted code as is without changes?..Also, which Protractor version are you using? And, if you can, please post the complete test you are working on (might be helpful to have more context). Thanks!

Comment: @wolfsbane I'll be afk for a while, I'll come back and respond in case you will not solve the problem by then. Thanks.

Comment: Its just a simple login page. I'm afraid I can't share the complete test. The protractor version is 3.3.0

Comment: @alecxe .. I am able to reproduce the error .. Please check below  @wolfsbane .. Its not advisable to go with `console.log(value)` as they are executed right at the beginning and they are not in sync with protractor control flow

Comment: @alecxe.. I somehow got rid of the error when I wrote the entire script again. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents on this ... I am reporting my observation below. I was able to reproduce the above stated error by passing `null` in `xpath` of the`elementFinder` which was passed as an argument in `browser.executeScript`

The below code when executed with `a = null` throws the error we are looking out for

```
it('check', function () {
    browser.get("http://www.protractortest.org/");
    //var a = "//a[contains(@class,'github')]";
    var a = null;
    browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', element(by.xpath(a)))
    });
```

Error Stack

```
  Stack:
    WebDriverError: Cannot find elements when the XPath expression is null.
        at WebDriverError (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:10)
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:639:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:538:13)
        at C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:472:11
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
        at C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2820:25
        at C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
    From: Task: WebDriver.findElements(By(xpath, null))
        at WebDriver.schedule (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:377:17)
        at WebDriver.findElements (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:926:22)
        at C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:161:44
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
        at C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2775:27
        at C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
    From: Task: WebDriver.executeScript()
        at WebDriver.schedule (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:377:17)
        at WebDriver.executeScript (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:526:16)
        at ProtractorBrowser.to.(anonymous function) [as executeScript] (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:59:29)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aditya\WebstormProjects\demo\demo2.js:10:17)
        at C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:94:23
        at new ManagedPromise (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1082:7)
        at controlFlowExecute (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:80:18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
        at C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2820:25
    From: Task: Run it(" through Gmail Account") in control flow
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:79:14)
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aditya\WebstormProjects\demo\demo2.js:5:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aditya\WebstormProjects\demo\demo2.js:4:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 1.957 seconds
```

Possible Root Cause could be the variable `desiredXpath` is being passed null and we cannot go with `console.log()` as they are not in sync with protractor Control flow and anything could have happened in between

Comment: i appreciate the effort but the click method is in a different file and i'm sending the xpath from the first file as an argument. So, I dont see any reason why async could be the case here.